# nodejs form cannot read property 'docreate' of undefined

Tags: json, node.js, express, model-view-controller

I'm a new in nodejs, and trying to create a new MVC application with expressjs. I have a html form with "POST" method and when i submit that some error showing.
Cannot read property 'docreate' of undefined

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'docreate' of undefined
    at exports.save (C:\Users\Hieu Vo\Desktop\hellow\notes\routes\notes.js:13:18)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Hieu Vo\Desktop\hellow\notes\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Hieu Vo\Desktop\hellow\notes\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Hieu Vo\Desktop\hellow\notes\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Hieu Vo\Desktop\hellow\notes\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Hieu Vo\Desktop\hellow\notes\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Hieu Vo\Desktop\hellow\notes\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Hieu Vo\Desktop\hellow\notes\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (C:\Users\Hieu Vo\Desktop\hellow\notes\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Hieu Vo\Desktop\hellow\notes\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

here is `app.js` file

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var notes = require('./routes/notes');
var app = express();
// view engine setup
app.use('/noteadd', notes.add);
app.post('/notesave', notes.save);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.post('/', function(request, response){
  console.log(request.body);      // your JSON
   response.send(request.body);    // echo the result back
});
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});
// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
module.exports = app;
```

I have view file with name `noteedit.ejs`

```
<% include top %>
<p value='<%= docreate ? "create" : "update"%>'><%= docreate ? "create" : "update"%></p>
<form method='POST' action='/notesave'>
    <input type='hidden' name='docreate' value='<%= docreate ? "create" : "update"%>'>
    <p>Key: <input type='text' name='notekey' value='<%= note ? notekey : "" %>'></p>
    <p>Title: <input type='text' name='title' value='<%= note ? note.title : "" %>'></p>
    <br/>
    <textarea rows=5 cols=40 name='body'><%= note ? note.body : "" %></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
<% include bottom %>
```

and this is my save function

```
var notes = require('../models/notes');

exports.add = function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('noteedit', {
        title: "Add a note",
        docreate: true,
        notekey: "",
        note: undefined
    });
}

exports.save = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.body.docreate === 'create') {
        notes.create(req.body.notekey,
                     req.body.title,
                     req.body.body);
    } else {
        notes.update(req.body.notekey,
                     req.body.title,
                     req.body.body);
    }
    res.redirect('/noteview?key='+req.body.notekey);
}
```

please help me in my problem, thank you for your help.
Thank again.

Comment: can you check if what u r getting `req.body` before `if (req.body.docreate === 'create') {` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use  'body-parser'. Please Read [this](https://fullstack-developer.academy/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js/)

Answer (score 0):

In this part of the code:

```
exports.save = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.body.docreate === 'create') {
        notes.create(req.body.notekey,
                     req.body.title,
                     req.body.body);
    } else {
        notes.update(req.body.notekey,
                     req.body.title,
                     req.body.body);
    }
    res.redirect('/noteview?key='+req.body.notekey);
}
```

You are trying to get the property docreate of req.body and the error is saying that that property doesn't exist. Make sure it is defined before checking if it is equal to 'create'

Comment: thank  you very much, but seam like i missing some config about urlencoded.